# Convert a relative path that includes a drive letter to an absolute path for .NET file functions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

How can you convert a drive relative path such as `D:test.xml` into an absolute path that a function such as `XDocument.Load()` will accept. The D drive could have `D:\data` as its current working directory, for example, so `D:test.xml` would mean `D:\data\test.xml` . I've already tried such concoctions as `D:.\test.xml` .

Here is the error I get for something like `D:test.xml`:

> Invalid URI: A Dos path must be rooted, for example, 'c:\'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx). For example:

```
// should return "D:\data\test.xml" if the current working dir is "D:\data"
string absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath("D:test.xml");
```

If the CWD is `"D:\Data"`, `Path.GetFullPath("D:test.xml")` would indeed return `"D:\data\test.xml"`, as it would getting full path directly for "test.xml".

However, if using a different drive letter than the one used for the CWD, the result will not be consistent. For example `Path.GetFullPath("C:test.xml")` would return `"C:\test.xml".`

This is by design. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths.

> If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the
>   backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the
>   current directory *on the drive with the specified letter*. Note that
>   the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending
>   on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory"
>   operation *on that disk*.

[*Emphasis* added by me]

Comment: @Florin: It's by design. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths. There's also a recent article by Raymond Chen that explains some of the history behind these seemingly odd design decisions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx

Comment: thanks for the links and explanation. They did clarify things. +1. However, while the concept of current directory is interesting from a historical perspective, I am not sure it is a good practice for nowadays applications.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply use "test.xml" as a relative path and if the current folder is "D:\data", the full path would be resolved to "D:\Data\test.xml". This is also illustrated in the MSDN example for the Load() method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx

<strike>Please note that "driveLetter:fileName" is not a relative path in .Net.</strike> (Please read Update)

You can transform a relative path into a full path using Path.GetFullPath(), but you do not have to do that XDocument.Load(), since it will also accept relative paths.

**Update**
LukeH, thanks for pointing this out! "driveLetter:fileName" are accepted by Path.GetFullPath() and are computed as relative paths to the current directory of the specified drive, as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths).

The concept of current directory at drive level is inherited from the very old days of the DOS. Not necessarily a feature on which I would build modern applications.

Comment: But, the current working directory is on a different drive letter and therefore, this solution fails.

Comment: How can the current directory be on a different drive? It is on a different drive from what? You get the current directory of a .Net windows application using Environment.CurrentDirectory. If you do not edit that path while running the application, it will be the path from which the application was started.

Comment: It is on a different drive letter than the drive letter supplied on the command line. E.g., CWD is c:\test and arg is d:test.xml

Comment: Excuse me, but I am still not getting you. You are starting the app from "C:\test" and the xml file is in "D:\test\test.xml"?

Comment: yes, and if you type d: at the command prompt, you would see d:\test for that cmd session.

Comment: @Michael, I've just made a test to be sure. If you are in "C:\test" and type "D:", you will get to "D:", not to "D:\test", even if "D:\test" exists! Also, check my comment on the reply you marked as an answer. It does not solve the scenario you are talking about. I also don't think that what you are trying to achieve is a good practice. Relative paths make sense on the same drive. Accessing other drives should be made with absolute paths. There is no guarantee that you will have the same directory structure in the other driver, so that the path would still make sense in there.

Comment: @Florin: It's not about whether "D:\test" exists; it's about whether "D:\test" is set as the current working directory *for drive D*. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx for more info.

Comment: Florin, listen, if you are at a command prompt you have paths set for each drive letter. My question was for a command line app which made use of this. To give you a simple example, assuming c:\test and d:\test are valid directories, try this at a command prompt: d: & cd \test & c: & cd \test & dir d:

Comment: @Michael, the problem that you had is now clear to me. I was not aware of the drive specific current directory inherited by command prompt from the old DOS days and I thought you meant the current application directory. Are the drive specific CWDs a functionality that you use, or was it something requested for your application.

Comment: It is basic functionality that anybody who (proficiently) uses console apps tends to use as a shortcut.

Comment: Can't help thinking that this is quite a limited shortcut, considering that it would only work with directories from different drives. Much of the time when using directories from the same drive it will not be useful. I totally agree that it is a feature which users that are accustomed with it will want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Path.GetFullPath can work. see [the doc here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in Luke's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4370924/3195477), the solution is due to how the current working directory is used. As an addendum to that answer here is some background. There is seemingly strange behavior of whether the current working directory is per-drive *or not*. Here is a [blog article from Raymond Chen of Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563) which explains this.

I had to dig around a bit to find a good link for this, so I've copied the contents as well in case it goes bad.

> ### Why does each drive have its own current directory?
>
> Commenter Dean Earley asks,  "Why is there a 'current directory' AND
>   an current drive? Why not merge them?"
>
> Pithy answer: Originally, each drive had its own current directory,
>   but now they don't, but it looks like they do.
>
> Okay, let's unwrap that sentence. You actually know enough to answer
>   the question yourself; you just have to put the pieces together.
>
> Set the wayback machine to DOS 1.0. Each volume was represented by a
>   drive letter. There were no subdirectories. This behavior was carried
>   forward from CP/M.
>
> Programs from the DOS 1.0 era didn't understand subdirectories; they
>   referred to files by just drive letter and file name, for example,
>   B:PROGRAM.LST. Let's fire up the assembler (compilers were for rich
>   people) and assemble a program whose source code is on the A drive,
>   but sending the output to the B drive.
>
> ```
> A>asm foo         the ".asm" extension on "foo" is implied
> Assembler version blah blah blah
> Source File: FOO.ASM
> Listing file [FOO.LST]: NUL       throw away the listing file
> Object file [FOO.OBJ]: B:     send the object file to drive B
> Since we gave only a drive letter in response to the Object file prompt, the assembler defaults to a file name of FOO.OBJ, resulting in
> ```
>
> the object file being generated as B:FOO.OBJ.
>
> Okay, now let's introduce subdirectories into DOS 2.0. Suppose you
>   have want to assemble A:\SRC\FOO.ASM and put the result into
>   B:\OBJ\FOO.OBJ. Here's how you do it:
>
> ```
> A> B:
> B> CD \OBJ
> B> A:
> A> CD \SRC
> A> asm foo
> Assembler version blah blah blah
> Source File: FOO.ASM
> Listing file [FOO.LST]: NUL
> Object file [FOO.OBJ]: B:
> ```
>
> The assembler reads from A:FOO.ASM and writes to B:FOO.OBJ, but since
>   the current directory is tracked on a per-drive basis, the results are
>   A:\SRC\FOO.ASM and B:\OBJ\FOO.OBJ as desired. If the current directory
>   were not tracked on a per-drive basis, then there would be no way to
>   tell the assembler to put its output into a subdirectory. As a result,
>   DOS 1.0 programs were effectively limited to operating on files in the
>   root directory, which means that nobody would put files in
>   subdirectories (because their programs couldn't access them).
>
> From a DOS 1.0 standpoint, changing the current directory on a drive
>   performs the logical equivalent of changing media. "Oh look, a
>   completely different set of files!"
>
> Short attention span.
>
> Remembering the current directory for each drive has been preserved
>   ever since, at least for batch files, although there isn't actually
>   such a concept as a per-drive current directory in Win32. In Win32,
>   all you have is a current directory. The appearance that each drive
>   has its own current directory is a fake-out by cmd.exe, which uses
>   strange environment variables to create the illusion to batch files
>   that each drive has its own current directory.
>
> Dean continues, "Why not merge them? I have to set both the dir and
>   drive if i want a specific working dir."
>
> The answer to the second question is, "They already are merged. It's
>   cmd.exe that tries to pretend that they aren't." And if you want to
>   set the directory and the drive from the command prompt or a batch
>   file, just use the /D option to the CHDIR command:
>
> ```
> D:\> CD /D C:\Program Files\Windows NT
> C:\Program Files\Windows NT> _
> ```
>
> (Notice that the CHDIR command lets you omit quotation marks around
>   paths which contain spaces: Since the command takes only one path
>   argument, the lack of quotation marks does not introduce ambiguity.