# Is a process's current directory equals to its working directory?

Tags: .net, windows

Is current directory same as working directory?

when I start a program under the PATH search folders, will the first folder become its current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

There's one working directory, which is a complete path (including drive letter).

But there is a "current directory" for each drive, which affects drive-relative paths (of the form `D:name` with no backslash following the drive specification).  IIRC, these are stored in the table of environment variables.

The link is that the shell automatically updates a current directory whenever the working directory changes.  But other programs don't necessarily do this.

`PATH` search has no effect on current directory or working directory.  They are inherited from the parent, unless explicitly specified when starting a new process.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4370891/103167).

Answer (score 0):

"The current directory is distinct from the original directory, which is the one from which the process was started."...as pointed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)

Btw, regarding your question title, there is not current or working directory, there is something called "current working directory" (again, from the link above).

Within your application, you can't be sure where your current working directory will be when the application is started, but you can [set it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) if you want.

(my links are .net related, which might not be your technology of choice).

Answer (score 0):

"Current directory" is a property of an active process.

AFAIK, "Current directory", "Current Working Directory" and "Working Directory" are all synonyms for exactly the same thing.  They are *certainly* are in Linux, Java (and arguably .Net) land.  In Windows, however, a process can have a different "working directory" for each drive:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory
- [Python's os.listdir behaviour on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258993/pythons-os-listdir-behaviour-on-windows)

A program's "initial directory" is typically one of:

- the directory you start it in (from the command line),
- the directory the .exe is located in (if you double-click on it from Windows Explorer), or
- the directory specified by the desktop link (if you double-click a Windows shortcut)

In other words, "Initial directory" and "the directory the exe is located in" may be the same, or different.

- A running process's "Initial directory" has nothing directly to do with the "Path".

The path helps the OS *find* the .exe (in order to load and run it), but it is *not* used to assign "Initial directory".

'Hope that helps